# Swift UITableView get Selected table item

Tags: swift, uitableview

I intent to connect two UITableView in one ViewController with two different classes with different data and then get the item selected but i can't make it work

**AppController.swift**

class AppController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var projects_TableView: UITableView!  
@IBOutlet weak var hours_TableView: UITableView!

var projects_DataSource: TableViewProjects?
var hours_DataSource: TableViewHours?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    projects_DataSource = TableViewProjects()
    hours_DataSource = TableViewHours()
    projects_TableView.dataSource = projects_DataSource
    hours_TableView.dataSource = hours_DataSource

    println("Table Sources Success")
}


func TableProjectsSelected() {
    println("Selected Project Table")

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("projectTable", sender: AnyObject?())
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "projectTable" {
            //do stuff
            println("projectTable ID")
        }
    }
```

and **TableViewProjects.swift**

```
var items: [String] = ["Project 1", "Project 2", "Project 3"]

override init() {
    super.init()
}


//TABLE FUNCTIONS
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return items.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell:UITableViewCell=UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "projectcell")

    cell.textLabel!.text = items[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    println("Select From Class")

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let appController: AppController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SelectProjectAndHour") as! AppController

    appController.TableProjectsSelected()

}
```

I can't get a response from item selected from TableViewProjects.swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should add these codes below:

```
projects_TableView.delegate = projects_DataSource
hours_TableView.delegate = hours_DataSource
```